# SwiftUi NavigationLink opening multiple views at once

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

```
                NavigationStack {
                    TextField("Factor Name", text: $factName)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .padding()
                                    Picker("Factor Type:", selection: $factType, content: {
                                        Text("Numeric").tag("num")
                                        Text("Scale").tag("scale")
                                        Text("Yes / No").tag("yn")
                                       Text("Categorical").tag("cat")
                                    })
                    Spacer()
                    if factType == "scale" {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Scale: ")
                            TextField("Low", text: $scaleLow1)
                                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                            Text(" to ")
                            TextField("High", text: $scaleHigh1)
                                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        }
                    }
                    else if factType == "cat" {
                       ** NavigationLink("Add categories: ", destination: CategoryAdd(catArray: $catArray))
                    }**
                    Toggle(isOn: $setGoal) {
                        Text("Set-Goal:")
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    if setGoal {
                        if (factType == "num" || factType == "scale") {
                            Text("Successful day: ")
                            HStack {
                                Button("Exact") {
                                    numericButton = "exact"
                                }
                                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                                Button("Range") {
                                    numericButton = "range"
                                }
                                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                            }
                            if numericButton == "range"
                            {
                                TextField("Minimum", text: $successMin)
                                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                                TextField("Maximum", text: $successMax)
                                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                            }
                            if numericButton == "exact"
                            {
                                TextField("", text: $successExact)
                                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                            }
                        }
                        else if (factType == "cat")
                        {
                            **NavigationLink("Pick successful categories:", destination: CatGoalSelect(catArray: $catArray, successCats: $successCats, selected: [""]))**
                        }
                        else if (factType == "yn")
                        {
                            Picker("", selection: $successYN, content: {
                                Text("Yes")
                                Text("No")
                            })
                            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            Text("How often to succeed?")
                            Picker("", selection: $successFreq, content: {
                                  Text("Everyday").tag("Everyday")
                                  Text("Certain days of the week").tag("Certain days of the week")
                                  Text("Number of days per period").tag("Number of days per period")
                                  })
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        if successFreq == "Certain days of the week"
                        {
                           ** NavigationLink("Choose days of the week", destination: DoWGoalSelect(successDoW: $successDoW))**
                        }
```

I have three separate NavigationLinks (highlighted with asterisks) with three separate destination views; clicking on any link brings up a stack of all activated links' views (while setGoal is false only the CategoryAdd view is displayed - otherwise all three are opened). Within the destination view I use a button to dismiss.

I tried changing the syntax (using destination: or putting the view in the curly braces of the link). I wanted to use tag and selection but it's been deprecated. I put three NavigationLinks in a VStack and they worked correctly (opening only one view), so I feel like this is a bug, but I'm new to Swift, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

NavigationStack uses a different kind of NavigationLink it's the one that takes a value and has a matching .navigationDestination, eg

```
NavigationStack {
    List(parks) { park in
        NavigationLink(park.name, value: park)
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: Park.self) { park in
        ParkDetails(park: park)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can show the exact implementation of this using my code and not a list because I tried using .navigationDestination and it did not work